# Create and plot ROC curve with tidymodels

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, tidymodels

Trying out a classification bagged tree in tidymodels and all is good until I get to creating and plotting the ROC curve. Then I get an

```
# Error in 'roc_curve()': ! Can't rename variables in this context.
```

My csv and the script I've written are [here](https://github.com/lilperu/Churned)

Predicting on the train set produced no errors

```
predictions<- predict(model_bagged, bank_train, type= "prob") %>% bind_cols(bank_train)
```

and there's a .pred_yes column in the output, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from or what it means.

Comment: As per the help page of `roc_curve()` you just call the prediction variable in `...`.  Try `roc_curve(predictions, truth = still_customer, .pred_yes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `roc_curve()` function doesn't use the `estimate` argument, and instead needs you to pass in the columns of the estimated values unnamed, to the `...`, like so:

```r
roc_curve(predictions,
          truth = still_customer,
          .pred_yes)
```

This is the case for all the [class probability metrics](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/index.html#class-probability-metrics)

Comment: Thank you very much. The same appears to be the case for roc_auc().

Comment: I only get the expected curve (top left) when I use .pred_no. Why would that be?